# Deriving kinetic energy from Newton's Second Law (step I don't understand)

Tags: derivatives, physics, mathematical-physics, factoring

Hello so there is a step in deriving newton's second law into the Kinetic Energy I don't quite understand it goes like this:
$$\overrightarrow{F}\overrightarrow{v}=m\frac{d\overrightarrow{v}}{dt}\overrightarrow{v})$$
goes to this:
$$\overrightarrow{F}\overrightarrow{v}=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2}m\overrightarrow{v}\overrightarrow{v})$$
First I thought they just factored out $\frac{d}{dt}$, but then I couldn't explain why there is a 1/2 between the brackets.

If someone knows how to get from the first equation to the second it would be very much appreciated to tell me your thought process or whrite it out clearly

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Newton's second Law, we know that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\vec{F}=\vec{F}_{neta}=m\cdot \vec{a}$$
also we know that $$\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=\vec{v}(t)$$ $$\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}=\vec{a}(t)$$
So, we have $$\vec{F}_{neta}\vec{v}=(m \cdot \vec{a})\vec{v}=m\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\vec{v}$$

By other hand, we know that $$K=\frac{1}{2}m(|\vec{v}|)^{2}$$
where $K$ is the kinetic energy and $K$ is a scalar magnitude.

Note that $$\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v}=|\vec{v}|^{2}$$where $|\vec{v}|$ denote the magnitude of the vector $\vec{v}$.

Also, note that  $$\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{1}{2}m  \vec{v}\cdot \vec{v}\right)=\frac{1}{2}m \frac{d}{dt}(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v})=m\frac{d|\vec{v}|}{dt}$$

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I actually wanted to know how they got from the first equation shown above to the second equation. Thus how they factored out the d/dt(...).

Comment: Ok, I will write more details.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: @TheCreator I added more details :-)

Comment: a wow now I see it, I was overcomplicating it. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @TheCreator You're welcome :-)